# How to handle errors with multer?

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I need to upload images on server, but if it is not jpeg\png, or filesize > 10Mb, I need to show an error. Images uploading well, but when I am trying to upload .zip file, my console is empty, why my code can't handle an error?

```
var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, '../public/img/avatars')
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, ''+req.user._id+'')
        },
        fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
            if (file.mimetype !== 'image/png' && file.mimetype !== 'image/jpg' && file.mimetype !== 'image/gif' ) {
                console.log('Wrong format!');
                return cb(null, false, new Error('Wrong format!'));
            }
            if ( file.size > 10000 ){
                console.log('Too large!');
                return cb(null, false, new Error('Too large!'));
            }
            cb(null, true);
        }
    });

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post('/changeAvatar', upload.single('avatar'), function(req, res) {
    var id = req.user._id;
    res.redirect('/user/'+id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Done. Just remove fileFilter from storage function.

```
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, '../public/img/avatars')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, ''+req.user._id+'')
    }
});
function fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
    if (file.mimetype !== 'image/png' && file.mimetype !== 'image/jpg' && file.mimetype !== 'image/gif' ) {
        console.log('Неправильный формат изображения!');
        return cb(null, false);
    }
    if ( file.size > 10000 ){
        console.log('Изображение весит слишком много!');
        return cb(null, false);
    }
    cb(null, true);
}

var upload = multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: fileFilter });
```